# Unity, Coroutine Won't Start

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, ienumerator

I have a simple finite state machine written by me. I have transitions and states. Here's what `StateTransition` looks like from inside:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public delegate void ActionCaller(IEnumerator action); // Take note of this delegate

private readonly ActionCaller caller;
private readonly IEnumerator action; // This is my State action

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public void Execute()
{
    caller.Invoke(action); // Here I call my `action` through `caller`
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

And here's my `MonoBehaviour` code which creates this states:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
private void Start()
{
    // Here I initialize my states and pass a method which will be called in `StateTransition.Execute` to execute passed method and `CallAction` to start Coroutine in my `MonoBehaviour` class
    States = new Dictionary<State, StateTransition>()
    {
        { State.Idling, new StateTransition(State.Idling, DoNothing(), CallAction) },
        { State.WanderingAround, new StateTransition(State.WanderingAround, WanderAround(), CallAction) }
    };

    StateMachine = new FiniteStateMachine(new List<Transition>()
    {
        new Transition(States[State.Idling], States[State.WanderingAround], Input.Wandering),
        new Transition(States[State.WanderingAround], States[State.Idling], Input.Nothing)
    });

    StateMachine.NextState(Input.Wandering);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

private void CallAction(IEnumerator routine)
{
    if (currentActionCoroutine != null)
    {
        StopCoroutine(currentActionCoroutine);
    }

    currentActionCoroutine = StartCoroutine(routine); // This code right here starts my passed `routine`
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

And here's the problem, when I call my first `NextState` it calls `WanderAround` which then calls `DoNothing` and after that it should call `WanderAround` again just fine, but the problem is that it simply doesn't call it. There's not a single error happening. The coroutine just doesn't wants to start. But if I call in, let's say, `DoNothing` `StartCoroutine(WanderAround())` - it works! But not throught my weird `StateTransition/Action/Execute` relationship.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

private IEnumerator DoNothing()
{
    Debug.Log("DoNothing:Enter");

    do
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.5f);
    } while (CurrentState == State.Dead);

    Debug.Log("DoNothing:Exit");

    StateMachine.NextState(Input.Wandering); // Calls `StateTransition.Execute`
}

private IEnumerator WanderAround()
{
    Debug.Log("WanderAround:Enter");

    Vector2 randomPosition = new Vector2(Random.Range(-5f, 5f), Random.Range(-5f, 5f));

    movementController.RotateAndMoveTo(randomPosition, Genes[Gene.MovementSpeed], Genes[Gene.TurnSpeed]);

    while (movementController.IsMoving || movementController.IsRotating)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Time.deltaTime);
    }

    Debug.Log("WanderAround:Exit");

    StateMachine.NextState(Input.Nothing); // Calls `StateTransition.Execute`
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

What should I do? Thanks!

**P.S.** Really sorry if this doesn't make any sense to you, I just don't know how to explain it more clearer.

Comment: I am not sure but in the first line change void to coroutine. I mean
public delegate Coroutine ActionCaller(IEnumerator action);

Comment: What does `StateMachine.NextState` do? And what are `Input.Wandering` and `Input.Nothing`? ... Could you edit your provided code to turn it into a minimal reproduceable example?

Comment: @Chestera, I've tried this (and also different forms of this), unfortunately, it didn't help

Comment: @derHugo, `Input.Wandering` and `Input.Nothing` are not relevant here. `StateMachine.NextState` calls `StateTransition.Execute`.

Comment: Can you fill in the do something block?

Comment: @LeoBartkus, ok, I've added additional code, but it won't tell you much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

I changed my `action` type from `IEnumerator` to `System.Func<IEnumerator>` and... it worked!

Now my code looks like this:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public delegate void ActionCaller(IEnumerator action); // Take note of this delegate

private readonly ActionCaller caller;
private readonly System.Func<IEnumerator> action; // This is my State action

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public void Execute()
{
    caller(action()); // Here I call my `action` through `caller`
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

And in `StateTransition` constructor I pass `SomeFunc` instead of `SomeFunc()`.

Cheers!